# Laravel Excel exporting from view outputs unproper xls file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, maatwebsite-excel

I'm facing an issue related to **Laravel Excel 2.1**.

I want to simply download xls file created from a view.

The problem is that this simple code **works with xls on fresh instalation of laravel**, but in my custom application the xls export does not work (*pdf and csv export works well*):

Controller:

```
Excel::create('somefile', function($excel) {
        $excel->sheet('cos', function($sheet) {
            $sheet->loadView('payments.test');
        });
})->download('xls');
```

Blade:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>test/td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Additional information:**
I've compared configs and they are the same.
The file is downloaded properly but there is not data inside of it.

**Generated file looks like this:**
[image: Generated file]

What could be the problem?

Comment: mention the error message

Comment: Define does not work? Do you get errors? No output? Timeout?

Comment: No I do not get any errors. If you want I can share the output file.

Comment: The file is downloaded well.

Comment: can you give a sample 'does not work' screenshot, snippet, or error text that you got?

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin yes, I've put preview of the file.

Comment: Have you checked the laravel version, php version, etc?

Comment: PHP 7.1.8, Laravel 5.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching I have found the solution:

Before `Excel::create` method you should **clean the output buffer** and turn off output buffering by using:

```
ob_end_clean();
ob_start();
```